# VaError: mutable default <class 'official.modeling.optimization.configs.optimizer_config.SGDConfig'> for field sgd is not allowed: use default_factory

Tags: python, tensorflow

> ValueError: mutable default <class'official.modeling.optimization.configs.optimizer_config.SGDConfig'> for field sgd is not allowed: use default_factory

error while training tenserflow

- python:3.11
- os: windows
- Model: SSD MobileNet V2 FPNLite 320x320

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.